# Change text content in a iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe, translate

I've a tool that's it's not mine and it's in a subdomain: `app.domain.com`. This tool is in English, and these people don't want to translate it.

So I decided to translate in an iframe and changing text with jQuery (Google Translate doesn't Work), and in other subdomain `apps.domain.com`.

How can i do it? I search in this web, but I didn't get response.

This is my code, and it's not running:

```
<iframe src="http://app.domain.com" id='inneriframe' scrolling="no"></iframe>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#inneriframe").contents().find('body').text("Clientes");
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace('Password','<span class="stars stars5">* * * * *</span>'));
    $("#inneriframe").contents().text($(this).text().replace('Password','Name:')); 
});
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Since the iframe's content is from a different domain, it won't work...

Answer (score 0):

When you have the option to modify the "tool"(you didn't explain what exactly it is), set the [document.domain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.domain) property in both documents to `domain.com`.

Furthermore: Modify the contents of the iframe on `$("#inneriframe").load()` to be sure that the document inside the iframe has been loaded yet.